# Macro needs to be started multiple times

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to write a macro that filters the column F from second to last row to check if the values in the column are numeric and if the length is 5. A diffrent length is allowed if the value in the column G on the same row contains "TEST".If the value doesnt meet the criteria the row should be deleted. The macro seems to work but I need to start it multiple times to filter all the values. 
here is the macro:

```
Sub Makro1()
Dim lrow As Long
lrow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range("F2:F" & lrow)
    For Each cell In Rng
        If Not IsNumeric(cell) Or (Len(cell) <> 5 And 
            InStr(UCase(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value), "TEST") = 0) Then
            cell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The deletion of rows must be done _backwards_.

Comment: Use a `For` loop running backwards when deleting rows: `For i = lrow To 2 Step -1` and `Cells(i, "F")` to check values and finally `Rows(i).Delete`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, it uses backward loop, **which is recommended when iterating over colletion**, that we delete from:

```
Sub Makro1()
    Dim lrow As Long, i As Long, cellValue As String
    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lrow To 2 Step -1
        cellValue = Cells(i, "F").Value
        If Not (IsNumeric(cellValue) And Len(cellValue) = 5) And Cells(i, "G").Value = "TEST" Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: the if clause was a bit off i changed it to                                                   
`If Not IsNumeric(cellValue) Or (Len(cellValue) <> 5 And InStr(UCase(Cells(i, "G").Value), "TEST") = 0) Then`